# How to format control characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x

If I enter this list

```
b=[0x41,0x42,0x43,13,10,9,48]
```

in Python3 and join this as chr I get a nicely displayed string. .The control characters are visible in the way I would input it in the code.

```
>>> c=''.join(map(chr,b))
>>> c
'ABC\r\n\t0'
```

But if I call `print(c)` the control characters are used in their meaning.

```
ABC
        0
```

How can I convert the variable `c` so that `print(c)` will output the string as I see in in the Python shell? i.e. the `\n` character shall be display with `\` and `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python shell prints [`repr(c)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr). This function returns a printable representation of the given object. So if you want that output instead of the actual string, do:

```
b=[0x41,0x42,0x43,13,10,9,48]
c=''.join(map(chr,b))
print(repr(c))
```

This gives the output:

```
'ABC\r\n\t0'
```